# CSV Upload in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, upload

I am working on sql server. I am trying to insert a csv file into a table in the database. The process needs to be automated since it will be done on a monthly basis with many files. The issue that i am facing is, in the data the last row has an arrow in  it. It is not a character but seems to be because of the process' done to create the csv file. I want a way to upload all the data without that arrow. Number of rows changes every month.

Comment: "It's not a character"? It has to be, it's a csv file. At the end of the day, all it contains are a bunch of Comma Separated Values. We're got very little to work with here, no sample data, no detail of how your getting the data into SQL Server, what you've tried, and information that (seems) quite inaccurate 9as you say the "arrow" isn't a character, which seems very unlikely. You need to expand your question a lot more here. Have a look at the [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) page. Otherwise all I can suggest is, remove the final character of the last column in your last row.

Comment: I dont know how to upload a csv file here. I am using this query-    BULK INSERT [APR18_MIGRATION].[dbo].[Fund Non Unit - Current]
FROM '\\Actur1\e\Val System\Val\2018\2018Apr\Original Data\ACTDIF0060.csv'
WITH (fieldTERMINATOR=',',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',ERRORFILE = '\\Actur2\e\WorkMgmt\Aditya\SQL_MIGRATION\myRubbishData1.log'
,lastrow=505543);                        but i want to avoid using the last row function. how do i do that?

Comment: Do you have an ID column in your table `[APR18_MIGRATION].[dbo].[Fund Non Unit - Current]` that can be used to identify the final row inserted?

Comment: (P.S. `[Fund Non Unit - Current]` is an awful name for an object in SQL Server. Try to only use alphanumerics and underscores (`_`) in object names. Using special characters in names more than often makes things harder)

Comment: yes there is an ID column. But there doesnt seem to be a way to identify the arrow symbol

Answer (score 0):

Based on assumptions from these statements: *"yes there is an ID column"*, *"in the data the last row has an arrow in it"*, and the assumption that the "arrow" is the last character in the final row, in the most right column, you could use a CTE and an `UPDATE` statement. This is pseudo-SQL, however:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YourIDColumn DESC) AS RN
    FROM YourTable)
UPDATE CTE
SET TheLastColumn = LEFT(TheLastColumn, LEN(TheLastColumn) -1)
WHERE RN = 1;
```

If you simply have a row with just has the arrow, then use `DELETE` instead and remove the `SET`.

If this doesn't help, then post sample data, like I asked in my original comment, please.

Comment: How do i upload the sample data? Also how will this query insert data from my csv file to sql table?

Comment: Your comments implies you already had uploaded your data. Are you saying you haven't?

Comment: I have not uploaded the data in the sql database. That is what my concern is, i am not able to upload the data because of the arrow symbol

Comment: @Aditya that's completely different to what your post ask, which os how to remove the arrow from the final column. If you can't upload the data, why haven't you posted the error you've been receiving, and the code that you've been using to try and upload the data? Please reword your question to be applicable to the problem you're having.